# Some points advice in omnet++ and sumo

Tags: omnet++

Any one can advice me in following points

1-

```
<routes>

 <route id="r2" edges=" 194402098#0 194402098#1 248057688#0 248057688#1 "/>

<vType id="t2" accel="2.6" decel="3.0" sigma="0.5" length="5" minGap="2" maxSpeed="50" color="1,1,1"/> 

<flow id="f2" type="t2" route="r2" begin="0.00" period="1" depart = 0 and departSpeed="max" number="100"/>

</routes>
```

FYI i set the lane speed 30m/s .. If I using this code i will get fixed speed for the nodes i mean 50m/s even the lane speed 30m/s?

2- From where can read the average  speed for vehicles in sumo ?

3- From where i can see the speed of vehicles in omnet++ .

Thanks in advance

Comment: StackOverflow is all about finding good answers to (good) questions. You are asking three questions at once which makes it hard to find a good answer. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224 for detailed discussion.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I can answer 1 and 2.

1. No you won't. The speed is limited by the maximum allowed speed on the lane multiplied by the vehicle's chosen speed factor which is determined from a gaussian distribution using he values `speedFactor` and `speedDev` in the description of the vType. The defaults are 1 and 0 which means no speed deviations.
2. It depends on what you mean by average speed. Average speed of all vehicles on a single edge in an interval or average speed of the vehicle along the route. For the former use [meandata output](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Output/Lane-_or_Edge-based_Traffic_Measures) for the latter just generate tripinfo output using the option `--tripinfo-output out.xml`.
3. I think OmNet does not have its own speeds since it is only a network simulator.